# Multiple audio elements versus document.querySelector('audio');

Tags: jquery, audio, element, selector

I used css+javascript to customise the style of an audio element (audio tag).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  audio = document.querySelector('audio');
  etc...
```

This searches and returns only the first 'audio' element in the html (good).

Now I want to show the audio element multiple times in the same page, with a few styling variations and different mp3s.

How to modify the 'element' name, or id, of each audio element (which is by default 'audio' for all of them) so that I can then call each of them individually?

Comment: `let audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');` and then use `audio[1]`

Comment: Thank you. I tried, I still fail. I guess this time I need to hire someone that can help and teach me. Thank you again Anant (ps: I don't know anyone that I could hire, advices are welcome)

Comment: You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I think try to use class instead of id, since an id must be unique within a page. By using class, you can target each audio element individually or as a group.